# Both call by value and call by reference work?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I thought that calling function by value will never work, and I should always use call by reference, but trying this code...

```
// call by value 
#include<stdio.h>

int Add(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b ;
    return c ; 
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2 , y = 4 ;
    int z = Add(x,y);
    printf("%d\n",z); 
}
```

output will be: 6

it works fine in both ways (call by value & call by reference),

```
// call by reference
#include<stdio.h>

int Add(int* a, int* b)
{
    int c = *a + *b ;
    return c ; 
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2 , y = 4 ;
    int z = Add(&x,&y);
    printf("%d\n",z); 
}

output will be: 6
```

not like the famous swap function example - when calling by value it doesn't swap -

```
// call by value
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int a, int b)
{
   int temp;

   temp = b;
   b   =  a;
   a   = temp;   
}

int main()
{
   int x = 1 , y = 2;

   printf("x = %d , y = %d\n", x,y); 

   swap(x, y); 

   printf("after swapping\n"); 
   printf("x = %d , y = %d\n", x,y); 

   return 0;
}
```

.. it only worked calling by reference

```
// call by reference
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp;

   temp = *b;
   *b   = *a;
   *a   = temp;   
}

int main()
{
   int x = 1 , y = 2;

   printf("x = %d , y = %d\n", x,y); 

   swap(&x, &y); 

   printf("after swapping\n"); 
   printf("x = %d , y = %d\n", x,y); 

   return 0;
}
```

So How can I judge if "calling by value" going to work or not ?!

Comment: "famous swap function example"? what do you have in mind?

Comment: You have changed the signature of the method: `int Add(int* a, int* b)`. Clearly it will work with a `&a` and a `&b` now!

Comment: C does not support pass by reference. It is **strictly** pass by value. And it also does not support _methods_.

Comment: @rsp hehh? What's that? Please explain or remove the outright wrong comment.

Comment: @rsp: To elaborate on SouravGhosh's comment: That's nonsense! Of course you can return **the value** of a local variable.

Comment: @rsp: ???? you can return an integer: a copy is made!!

Comment: sorry I wasn't aware of "methods" as I'm new to programming languages, I edited my question also adding the example of the swap function

Answer (score -1):

> So How can I judge that call by value method is valid or not ?!

Well, it depends on what your function is about to do.

In your above example, you only *need* the values of (x,y) for computing, but you never plan to *change* their value during your function. While call-by-reference will work in this case, it is unneccessary.

In the other (indirectly given) example you obviously want to *change* two variable's content (that is - swap it). You can access these variables from the main-function in your Swap-function, but how can you make the change persistent? That's only possible by call-by-reference, because you have to write the changed content into a variable that survives the function.

The following will not work:

```
// call by value 
#include<stdio.h>

void Swap(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    // from here on a, b, c will be destroyed
    // therefore the change cannot be seen outside the function
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2 , y = 4 ;
    Swap(x,y);
    printf("x: %d --- y: %d\n",x,y); 
}
```

So as a rule to keep in mind:

If you want to make a change that's supposed to survive the function's end, use call-by-reference. If you just work with some data but do not want to (or must not) change their value, use call-by-value.

Comment: C does not support call by reference. The question is pointless.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the C standard where it specifies references. You apparently confuse C and C++.

Comment: I really don't see your problem. "Call-by-reference" is a _fixed term_ meaning that a function has access to (global) variables through pointers, which don't contain the var's value but their address. So yes, C does support call-by-reference, even if it uses pointers, which are a form of local variables. And no, I don't confuse it with C++ ;)

Comment: A pointer is **not** a reference. The term "pass by reference" commonly does not refer to pointers. Pointers are first class types passed by value like any other type in C. References are not. And pointers are not related to local/global (btw: the term "global" is not used in C, neither for scope nor storage duration).